# kubectl rollout does not provide an image flag

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to implement a rollback strategy for deployments using a CI pipeline. My goal is to rollback to a specific image version rather than using the generic black-box `revision number` of `kubernetes rollout`subcommand. Unfortunately, Kubernetes default rollback flags only provide `--to-revision` flag to select a revision number which doesn't give you any information about what image that revision is using.

```
$ kubectl rollout undo deployment/nginx-deployment --to-revision=2
```

Is there a way to know what image and tag that revision using? The `REVISION` numbers on doesn't tell much and will mean that I've to keep track in whatever way to know what image version is in each revision number. Overriding `CHANGE-CAUSE` to add more informatin in the annotations of the deployment I understand is not advisable

```bash
REVISION    CHANGE-CAUSE
1           kubectl create -f deployment.yaml --record
2           kubectl set image deployment/httpd-deployment httpd=httpd:1.9.1
3           kubectl set image deployment/htppd-deployment httpd=nginx:1.91
```

I am looking for something like this in my CI pipeline with `--to-image` sort of flag

```bash
$ kubectl rollout undo deployment/nginx-deployment --to-revision=2 --to-image=httpd:1.7
```

Knowing that `--to-image` flag doesn't  exist, will that mean me just totally abandoning the rollout command and just redeploying with a previous image like below. (I'm thinking this is not actually harnessing rollout capability)

```bash
$ kubectl set image deployment/httpd-deployment httpd=httpd:1.9.1
```

Any better way to implement Kubernetes Rollback to a previous specific deployment image?

Comment: Explicitly setting the image as you've shown is a fine way to "roll back".  If you do use Helm or a similar tool, asking it to "upgrade" to an older image tag makes sense (the `helm rollback` command will in fact effectively `kubectl apply` a new Deployment spec with the old tag).  I very rarely use the `kubectl rollout` series of commands.

Comment: This looks good to me to implement. Thanks